# set start point in c3 Donut chart

Tags: jquery, d3.js, c3.js

hi i am using c3js donut chart . everything is fine. only one issue i facing is the start point && direction. i try to change the angle of the chart but it is not working. what i want is to start chart on top of the round with clock wise direction.

this is the code i am using.

```
_chartdata = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#handler',
        data: {
            columns: [],
            type: 'donut',
            colors: colors,
        },
        donut: {
            title: "0%",
            label: {
                show: false
            },
            width: 20,
        },
        startAngle: -90,
    });
```

i tried to change the angle and direction by adding start angle, but it is not working: is there any way to change the angle?

[image]

this is what i want.

[image]

and this is what i getting now

Comment: AFAIK c3.js donut has no startAngle option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the donut in the onrendered function to do this. It's a bit more complicated than it would be because the text elements need returned to normal (you don't want them back-to-front and at an angle) and existing transforms need to be accommodated.

Change the angle variable for a new start angle and the direction (either 1 or -1)

```
onrendered: function () {
    var angle = 180;
    var direction = -1;

    d3.select("#handler").selectAll(".c3-chart-arcs").each (function (d, i) {
        var d3elem = d3.select(this);
        var current = d3elem.attr("transform");
        var currentTrans = d3.transform(current);
        currentTrans.rotate = angle;
        currentTrans.scale[0] = direction;
        d3elem.attr("transform", currentTrans.toString());   // flips n rotates

        d3elem.selectAll("text").each (function () {
            var d3elem = d3.select(this);
            var current2 = d3elem.attr("transform");
            var currentTrans2 = d3.transform(current2);
                currentTrans2.rotate = angle;
                currentTrans2.scale[0] = direction;
                d3elem.attr("transform", currentTrans2.toString());  
        });
    })
}
```

PS this adjusts for the tooltip, it gets the x and y by measuring against an element that hasn't been scaled and twisted:

```
tooltip: {
    position: function (data, width, height, element) {
        var m = d3.mouse(d3.select("#handler .c3-event-rects").node());
      var top = m[1] + 15;
      var left = m[0];
      return {top: top, left: left};
  }
},
```

**Edit 3:**

Rounded corners is even more involved. Basically d3 lets you set a cornerRadius on an arc, but c3 doesn't expose this. The only way (AFAIK) to do it is to replace the two arc drawing functions in c3 before you set up your chart, with two exactly the same functions apart from adding in a corner radius value (which I've set

```
c3.chart.internal.fn.getSvgArc = function () {
    var $$ = this,
        arc = $$.d3.svg.arc().outerRadius($$.radius).innerRadius($$.innerRadius).cornerRadius(($$.radius - $$.innerRadius) / 2),
        newArc = function newArc(d, withoutUpdate) {
        var updated;
        if (withoutUpdate) {
            return arc(d);
        } // for interpolate
        updated = $$.updateAngle(d);
        return updated ? arc(updated) : "M 0 0";
    };
    // TODO: extends all function
    newArc.centroid = arc.centroid;
    return newArc;
};

c3.chart.internal.fn.getSvgArcExpanded = function (rate) {
    var $$ = this,
        arc = $$.d3.svg.arc().outerRadius($$.radiusExpanded * (rate ? rate : 1)).innerRadius($$.innerRadius).cornerRadius(($$.radius - $$.innerRadius) / 2);
    return function (d) {
        var updated = $$.updateAngle(d);
        return updated ? arc(updated) : "M 0 0";
    };
};
```

You might at this point be considering beavers point about a chart that does this without this amount of hacking :-) (if highcharts does the rounded corner thing)

https://jsfiddle.net/np494kb6/6/

Comment: @ mgraham  but why my title rotate to oppsite direction ?

Comment: my title (the bit in the middle) stays where it is in the fiddle. You're right about the tooltip though, that's annoying, but I think I've managed to fix that in the edit (works in the fiddle at least)

Comment: Also see what you mean about the title, it does rotate again if updated, basically the scale and rotation gets done twice. I've used the d3.transform function in the latest edit to parse the existing transform string so this shouldn't happen again.

Comment: @ mgraham and also is there any idea to adjust the style of that blue color part in chart..i need to adjust the edge . same like the another image in top>>

Comment: voted up, but I think it's better to use a chart library which implements startAngle natively (e.g. Highcharts, see [API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie.startAngle), [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/8aa5egjf/))

Comment: yeh, but I like c3 because I use d3 a lot, and also I can basically wrestle it into doing stuff it doesn't expose in the configuration. I wish it was just maintained more regularly, people keep asking for this stuff on their github page.